# AWS upload files to S3 server using only ID and key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

Is there any way I can load objects into buckets for a S3 server using my ID and Key given by an administrator? The AWS console login requires an email address and password as opposed to the latter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the aws-cli: https://github.com/timkay/aws
You have full access(EC2, ELB, S3) as in AWS console login only with the ID and KEY.